# Why is ROC not representative of Neural Net model in R

Tags: r, neural-network, roc

**I am wondering why my ROC chart is likely wrong**

Follow the packages used:

```
library(datasets)
library(caTools)
library(neuralnet)
library(ROCR)
```

Follow my script and the ROC result that I am getting:

**1. First step I categorize the species in 1,2,3**

```
data(iris)

iris$Species <- ifelse(iris$Species=='setosa',1,ifelse(iris$Species=='versicolor',2,3))
```

**2. Second step, normalize the data**

```
scaled.dat<-scale(iris[,1:4])
```

**3. Third step, split the data: train and test**

```
split <- sample.split(iris$Species, SplitRatio = 0.70)
treino <- subset(iris, split == TRUE)
teste <- subset(iris, split == FALSE)
```

**4. Fourth step, convert strings variables in the standard format**

```
feats <- names(teste[,c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width')])

    f <- paste(feats,collapse=' + ')
    f <- paste('Species ~',f)
    
    f <- as.formula(f)
```

**5. Fifth step, run neuralnet package and confusion matrix analyses**

```
nn <- neuralnet(f, treino, hidden = c(4),linear.output=TRUE, threshold=0.01)

      plot(nn)
        pr.nn <- compute(nn, teste[, 1:4])
        
        results <- data.frame(actual = teste$Species, prediction = pr.nn$net.result)
        results
        roundedresults<-sapply(results,round,digits=0)
        roundedresultsdf=data.frame(roundedresults)
        attach(roundedresultsdf)
        table(actual,prediction)

head(roundedresultsdf$prediction)
```

> 1 1 1 1 1 1

```
head(roundedresultsdf$actual)
```

> 1 1 1 1 1 1

**6. Sixth step, ROC analysis**

```
roundedresultsdf$label <- ifelse(roundedresultsdf$actual==roundedresultsdf$prediction,1,0)
  pred <- prediction(roundedresultsdf$prediction,roundedresultsdf$label)
  perf1 <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
  plot(perf1)
  abline(a=0, b= 1)
```

### ROC Results

[image]

### **Question**

*Why is my ROC result so different than the model result. Should have been something more curvy as ROC chart of good models.*

### **Result**

This is a problem of `multiclass ROC`, follow the right code:

```
install.packages('pROC')
  library(pROC)
 roc.multi <- multiclass.roc(results$actual, results$prediction)
  auc(roc.multi)
  rs <- roc.multi[['rocs']]
  plot.roc(rs[[1]])
  legend("bottomleft", inset=.02, title="Número de classes",
         c("1","2","3"), fill=c("yellow", "red", "green"), horiz=TRUE, cex=0.8)
  sapply(1:length(rs),function(i) lines.roc(rs[[i]],col=i))
```

[image]

Comment: Does your`pred` variable only contain 0s and 1s? If so, then that's what your ROC curve should look like. If you want it to be smoother, `pred` has to be a continuous variable and not the predicted labels.

Comment: Thanks @Zelazny7 but the function prediciton are your continuous predictions of the classification, the labels are the binary truth for each variable

Comment: Your question is actually "How to plot ROC curves in multiclass classification?", which has some good answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/how-to-plot-roc-curves-in-multiclass-classification

Comment: Thanks @FatihAkici, you solved my problem!

Comment: Oh glad to hear that, @ArthurVaz. Good luck!